# Add profile to existing springBoot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have already spring boot application with default profile. Now I want the same application to work on different environments(dev,test,prod). Using spring profile its possible. We are manually changing the database properties and building the application in production and test environment.

Here is the version details of my Spring Boot App

1.Java 1.8 
2.Spring Boot : 1.5.2.RELEASE
3.Oracle database: 12

The requirement is to make the existing spring boot application to work dynamically using maven and spring  profile features. 
1. for local environment we are using STS-IDE.
2. For test & prod environment we are using jenkins.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What are the current existing profiles? what should be the difference between the existing ones and new ones?

Comment: If you can provide an application.properties file template, an application.yml template can be created that handles all the profiles.

Comment: you can take any default spring profile.

spring.datasource.url=localURL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracleDriver
spring.datasource.username=localUser
spring.datasource.password=localPswd